# get single value from json string

Tags: java

i have Json string like this where the function return List:

```
[
    {
        "name": "DEFAULT",
        "effectiveDate": "Apr 19, 2018 3:35:31 PM",
        "currencies": [
            "IDR"
        ],
        "products": [
            {
                "type": "BASE",
                "name": "PostPaid",
                "plans": [
                    {
                        "name": "postpaid-monthly-fix",
                        "billingPeriod": "MONTHLY",
                        "phases": [
                            {
                                "type": "EVERGREEN",
                                "prices": [
                                    {
                                        "currency": "IDR",
                                        "value": 300000
                                    }
                                ],
                                "fixedPrices": [],
                                "duration": {
                                    "unit": "UNLIMITED",
                                    "number": -1
                                },
                                "usages": []
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "postpaid-monthly-trial1",
                        "billingPeriod": "MONTHLY",
                        "phases": [
                            {
                                "type": "TRIAL",
                                "prices": [],
                                "fixedPrices": [
                                    {
                                        "currency": "IDR",
                                        "value": 0
                                    }
                                ],
                                "duration": {
                                    "unit": "DAYS",
                                    "number": 1
                                },
                                "usages": []
                            },
                            {
                                "type": "EVERGREEN",
                                "prices": [
                                    {
                                        "currency": "IDR",
                                        "value": 250000
                                    }
                                ],
                                "fixedPrices": [],
                                "duration": {
                                    "unit": "UNLIMITED",
                                    "number": -1
                                },
                                "usages": []
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "postpaid-monthly-trial7",
                        "billingPeriod": "MONTHLY",
                        "phases": [
                            {
                                "type": "TRIAL",
                                "prices": [],
                                "fixedPrices": [
                                    {
                                        "currency": "IDR",
                                        "value": 0
                                    }
                                ],
                                "duration": {
                                    "unit": "DAYS",
                                    "number": 7
                                },
                                "usages": []
                            },
                            {
                                "type": "EVERGREEN",
                                "prices": [
                                    {
                                        "currency": "IDR",
                                        "value": 350000
                                    }
                                ],
                                "fixedPrices": [],
                                "duration": {
                                    "unit": "UNLIMITED",
                                    "number": -1
                                },
                                "usages": []
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "included": [],
                "available": []
            },
            {
                "type": "BASE",
                "name": "PrePaid",
                "plans": [
                    {
                        "name": "prepaid-signature-item",
                        "billingPeriod": "NO_BILLING_PERIOD",
                        "phases": [
                            {
                                "type": "EVERGREEN",
                                "prices": [],
                                "fixedPrices": [],
                                "duration": {
                                    "unit": "UNLIMITED",
                                    "number": -1
                                },
                                "usages": [
                                    {
                                        "billingPeriod": "DAILY",
                                        "tiers": [
                                            {
                                                "blocks": [
                                                    {
                                                        "unit": "item",
                                                        "size": "1.0",
                                                        "max": "5.0",
                                                        "prices": [
                                                            {
                                                                "currency": "IDR",
                                                                "value": 250000
                                                            }
                                                        ]
                                                    }
                                                ],
                                                "limits": [],
                                                "fixedPrice": [],
                                                "recurringPrice": []
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "included": [],
                "available": []
            }
        ],
        "priceLists": [
            {
                "name": "DEFAULT",
                "plans": [
                    "postpaid-monthly-fix",
                    "postpaid-monthly-trial1",
                    "postpaid-monthly-trial7",
                    "prepaid-signature-item"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "DEFAULT",
        "effectiveDate": "Apr 20, 2018 3:35:31 PM",
        "currencies": [
            "IDR"
        ],
        "products": [
            {
                "type": "BASE",
                "name": "PostPaid",
                "plans": [
                    {
                        "name": "postpaid-monthly-fix",
                        "billingPeriod": "MONTHLY",
                        "phases": [
                            {
                                "type": "EVERGREEN",
                                "prices": [
                                    {
                                        "currency": "IDR",
                                        "value": 300000
                                    }
                                ],
                                "fixedPrices": [],
                                "duration": {
                                    "unit": "UNLIMITED",
                                    "number": -1
                                },
                                "usages": []
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "postpaid-monthly-trial1",
                        "billingPeriod": "MONTHLY",
                        "phases": [
                            {
                                "type": "TRIAL",
                                "prices": [],
                                "fixedPrices": [
                                    {
                                        "currency": "IDR",
                                        "value": 0
                                    }
                                ],
                                "duration": {
                                    "unit": "DAYS",
                                    "number": 1
                                },
                                "usages": []
                            },
                            {
                                "type": "EVERGREEN",
                                "prices": [
                                    {
                                        "currency": "IDR",
                                        "value": 250000
                                    }
                                ],
                                "fixedPrices": [],
                                "duration": {
                                    "unit": "UNLIMITED",
                                    "number": -1
                                },
                                "usages": []
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "postpaid-monthly-trial7",
                        "billingPeriod": "MONTHLY",
                        "phases": [
                            {
                                "type": "TRIAL",
                                "prices": [],
                                "fixedPrices": [
                                    {
                                        "currency": "IDR",
                                        "value": 0
                                    }
                                ],
                                "duration": {
                                    "unit": "DAYS",
                                    "number": 7
                                },
                                "usages": []
                            },
                            {
                                "type": "EVERGREEN",
                                "prices": [
                                    {
                                        "currency": "IDR",
                                        "value": 350000
                                    }
                                ],
                                "fixedPrices": [],
                                "duration": {
                                    "unit": "UNLIMITED",
                                    "number": -1
                                },
                                "usages": []
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "included": [],
                "available": []
            },
            {
                "type": "BASE",
                "name": "PrePaid",
                "plans": [
                    {
                        "name": "prepaid-signature-item",
                        "billingPeriod": "NO_BILLING_PERIOD",
                        "phases": [
                            {
                                "type": "EVERGREEN",
                                "prices": [],
                                "fixedPrices": [],
                                "duration": {
                                    "unit": "UNLIMITED",
                                    "number": -1
                                },
                                "usages": [
                                    {
                                        "billingPeriod": "NO_BILLING_PERIOD",
                                        "tiers": [
                                            {
                                                "blocks": [
                                                    {
                                                        "unit": "item",
                                                        "size": "1.0",
                                                        "max": "5.0",
                                                        "prices": [
                                                            {
                                                                "currency": "IDR",
                                                                "value": 250000
                                                            }
                                                        ]
                                                    }
                                                ],
                                                "limits": [],
                                                "fixedPrice": [],
                                                "recurringPrice": []
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "included": [],
                "available": []
            }
        ],
        "priceLists": [
            {
                "name": "DEFAULT",
                "plans": [
                    "postpaid-monthly-fix",
                    "postpaid-monthly-trial1",
                    "postpaid-monthly-trial7",
                    "prepaid-signature-item"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "DEFAULT",
        "effectiveDate": "Apr 21, 2018 3:35:31 PM",
        "currencies": [
            "IDR"
        ],
        "products": [
            {
                "type": "BASE",
                "name": "PostPaid",
                "plans": [
                    {
                        "name": "postpaid-monthly-fix",
                        "billingPeriod": "MONTHLY",
                        "phases": [
                            {
                                "type": "EVERGREEN",
                                "prices": [
                                    {
                                        "currency": "IDR",
                                        "value": 300000
                                    }
                                ],
                                "fixedPrices": [],
                                "duration": {
                                    "unit": "UNLIMITED",
                                    "number": -1
                                },
                                "usages": []
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "postpaid-monthly-trial1",
                        "billingPeriod": "MONTHLY",
                        "phases": [
                            {
                                "type": "TRIAL",
                                "prices": [],
                                "fixedPrices": [
                                    {
                                        "currency": "IDR",
                                        "value": 0
                                    }
                                ],
                                "duration": {
                                    "unit": "DAYS",
                                    "number": 1
                                },
                                "usages": []
                            },
                            {
                                "type": "EVERGREEN",
                                "prices": [
                                    {
                                        "currency": "IDR",
                                        "value": 250000
                                    }
                                ],
                                "fixedPrices": [],
                                "duration": {
                                    "unit": "UNLIMITED",
                                    "number": -1
                                },
                                "usages": []
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "postpaid-monthly-trial7",
                        "billingPeriod": "MONTHLY",
                        "phases": [
                            {
                                "type": "TRIAL",
                                "prices": [],
                                "fixedPrices": [
                                    {
                                        "currency": "IDR",
                                        "value": 0
                                    }
                                ],
                                "duration": {
                                    "unit": "DAYS",
                                    "number": 7
                                },
                                "usages": []
                            },
                            {
                                "type": "EVERGREEN",
                                "prices": [
                                    {
                                        "currency": "IDR",
                                        "value": 350000
                                    }
                                ],
                                "fixedPrices": [],
                                "duration": {
                                    "unit": "UNLIMITED",
                                    "number": -1
                                },
                                "usages": []
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "included": [],
                "available": []
            },
            {
                "type": "BASE",
                "name": "PrePaid",
                "plans": [
                    {
                        "name": "prepaid-signature-item",
                        "billingPeriod": "NO_BILLING_PERIOD",
                        "phases": [
                            {
                                "type": "EVERGREEN",
                                "prices": [],
                                "fixedPrices": [],
                                "duration": {
                                    "unit": "UNLIMITED",
                                    "number": -1
                                },
                                "usages": [
                                    {
                                        "billingPeriod": "DAILY",
                                        "tiers": [
                                            {
                                                "blocks": [
                                                    {
                                                        "unit": "item",
                                                        "size": "1.0",
                                                        "max": "5.0",
                                                        "prices": [
                                                            {
                                                                "currency": "IDR",
                                                                "value": 250000
                                                            }
                                                        ]
                                                    }
                                                ],
                                                "limits": [],
                                                "fixedPrice": [],
                                                "recurringPrice": []
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "included": [],
                "available": []
            }
        ],
        "priceLists": [
            {
                "name": "DEFAULT",
                "plans": [
                    "postpaid-monthly-fix",
                    "postpaid-monthly-trial1",
                    "postpaid-monthly-trial7",
                    "prepaid-signature-item"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "DEFAULT",
        "effectiveDate": "Apr 21, 2018 3:38:31 PM",
        "currencies": [
            "IDR"
        ],
        "products": [
            {
                "type": "BASE",
                "name": "PostPaid",
                "plans": [
                    {
                        "name": "postpaid-monthly-fix",
                        "billingPeriod": "MONTHLY",
                        "phases": [
                            {
                                "type": "EVERGREEN",
                                "prices": [
                                    {
                                        "currency": "IDR",
                                        "value": 300000
                                    }
                                ],
                                "fixedPrices": [],
                                "duration": {
                                    "unit": "UNLIMITED",
                                    "number": -1
                                },
                                "usages": []
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "postpaid-monthly-trial1",
                        "billingPeriod": "MONTHLY",
                        "phases": [
                            {
                                "type": "TRIAL",
                                "prices": [],
                                "fixedPrices": [
                                    {
                                        "currency": "IDR",
                                        "value": 0
                                    }
                                ],
                                "duration": {
                                    "unit": "DAYS",
                                    "number": 1
                                },
                                "usages": []
                            },
                            {
                                "type": "EVERGREEN",
                                "prices": [
                                    {
                                        "currency": "IDR",
                                        "value": 250000
                                    }
                                ],
                                "fixedPrices": [],
                                "duration": {
                                    "unit": "UNLIMITED",
                                    "number": -1
                                },
                                "usages": []
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "postpaid-monthly-trial7",
                        "billingPeriod": "MONTHLY",
                        "phases": [
                            {
                                "type": "TRIAL",
                                "prices": [],
                                "fixedPrices": [
                                    {
                                        "currency": "IDR",
                                        "value": 0
                                    }
                                ],
                                "duration": {
                                    "unit": "DAYS",
                                    "number": 7
                                },
                                "usages": []
                            },
                            {
                                "type": "EVERGREEN",
                                "prices": [
                                    {
                                        "currency": "IDR",
                                        "value": 350000
                                    }
                                ],
                                "fixedPrices": [],
                                "duration": {
                                    "unit": "UNLIMITED",
                                    "number": -1
                                },
                                "usages": []
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "included": [],
                "available": []
            },
            {
                "type": "BASE",
                "name": "PrePaid",
                "plans": [
                    {
                        "name": "prepaid-signature-item",
                        "billingPeriod": "NO_BILLING_PERIOD",
                        "phases": [
                            {
                                "type": "EVERGREEN",
                                "prices": [],
                                "fixedPrices": [],
                                "duration": {
                                    "unit": "UNLIMITED",
                                    "number": -1
                                },
                                "usages": [
                                    {
                                        "billingPeriod": "DAILY",
                                        "tiers": [
                                            {
                                                "blocks": [
                                                    {
                                                        "unit": "item",
                                                        "size": "1.0",
                                                        "max": "5.0",
                                                        "prices": [
                                                            {
                                                                "currency": "IDR",
                                                                "value": 250000
                                                            }
                                                        ]
                                                    }
                                                ],
                                                "limits": [],
                                                "fixedPrice": [],
                                                "recurringPrice": []
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "included": [],
                "available": []
            }
        ],
        "priceLists": [
            {
                "name": "DEFAULT",
                "plans": [
                    "postpaid-monthly-fix",
                    "postpaid-monthly-trial1",
                    "postpaid-monthly-trial7",
                    "prepaid-signature-item"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

where json build by this code:

```
String json = new Gson().toJson(price);
```

then i want to get single value, for example :

```
"plans":["postpaid-monthly-fix","postpaid-monthly-trial1","postpaid-monthly-trial7","prepaid-signature-item"]
```

i try with json.get("plans") but get syntax erro, any clue ?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to get the fields from your `price` POJO?

Comment: price return from List<Catalog>, how to get single value ? if i use price.get(2) by index the size return is just 1, then when price.get(0) is return all in line

Comment: Json is the String. its not a List<>.  json.get("plans") is the wrong statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
String s = "[{\"name\":\"DEFAULT\",\"effectiveDate\":\"Apr 19, 2018 3:35:31 PM\",\"currencies\":[\"IDR\"],\"products\":[{\"type\":\"BASE\",\"name\":\"PostPaid\",\"plans\":[{\"name\":\"postpaid-monthly-fix\",\"billingPeriod\":\"MONTHLY\",\"phases\":[{\"type\":\"EVERGREEN\",\"prices\":[{\"currency\":\"IDR\",\"value\":300000}],\"fixedPrices\":[],\"duration\":{\"unit\":\"UNLIMITED\",\"number\":-1},\"usages\":[]}]},{\"name\":\"postpaid-monthly-trial1\",\"billingPeriod\":\"MONTHLY\",\"phases\":[{\"type\":\"TRIAL\",\"prices\":[],\"fixedPrices\":[{\"currency\":\"IDR\",\"value\":0}],\"duration\":{\"unit\":\"DAYS\",\"number\":1},\"usages\":[]},{\"type\":\"EVERGREEN\",\"prices\":[{\"currency\":\"IDR\",\"value\":250000}],\"fixedPrices\":[],\"duration\":{\"unit\":\"UNLIMITED\",\"number\":-1},\"usages\":[]}]},{\"name\":\"postpaid-monthly-trial7\",\"billingPeriod\":\"MONTHLY\",\"phases\":[{\"type\":\"TRIAL\",\"prices\":[],\"fixedPrices\":[{\"currency\":\"IDR\",\"value\":0}],\"duration\":{\"unit\":\"DAYS\",\"number\":7},\"usages\":[]},{\"type\":\"EVERGREEN\",\"prices\":[{\"currency\":\"IDR\",\"value\":350000}],\"fixedPrices\":[],\"duration\":{\"unit\":\"UNLIMITED\",\"number\":-1},\"usages\":[]}]}],\"included\":[],\"available\":[]},{\"type\":\"BASE\",\"name\":\"PrePaid\",\"plans\":[{\"name\":\"prepaid-signature-item\",\"billingPeriod\":\"NO_BILLING_PERIOD\",\"phases\":[{\"type\":\"EVERGREEN\",\"prices\":[],\"fixedPrices\":[],\"duration\":{\"unit\":\"UNLIMITED\",\"number\":-1},\"usages\":[{\"billingPeriod\":\"DAILY\",\"tiers\":[{\"blocks\":[{\"unit\":\"item\",\"size\":\"1.0\",\"max\":\"5.0\",\"prices\":[{\"currency\":\"IDR\",\"value\":250000}]}],\"limits\":[],\"fixedPrice\":[],\"recurringPrice\":[]}]}]}]}],\"included\":[],\"available\":[]}],\"priceLists\":[{\"name\":\"DEFAULT\",\"plans\":[\"postpaid-monthly-fix\",\"postpaid-monthly-trial1\",\"postpaid-monthly-trial7\",\"prepaid-signature-item\"]}]},{\"name\":\"DEFAULT\",\"effectiveDate\":\"Apr 20, 2018 3:35:31 PM\",\"currencies\":[\"IDR\"],\"products\":[{\"type\":\"BASE\",\"name\":\"PostPaid\",\"plans\":[{\"name\":\"postpaid-monthly-fix\",\"billingPeriod\":\"MONTHLY\",\"phases\":[{\"type\":\"EVERGREEN\",\"prices\":[{\"currency\":\"IDR\",\"value\":300000}],\"fixedPrices\":[],\"duration\":{\"unit\":\"UNLIMITED\",\"number\":-1},\"usages\":[]}]},{\"name\":\"postpaid-monthly-trial1\",\"billingPeriod\":\"MONTHLY\",\"phases\":[{\"type\":\"TRIAL\",\"prices\":[],\"fixedPrices\":[{\"currency\":\"IDR\",\"value\":0}],\"duration\":{\"unit\":\"DAYS\",\"number\":1},\"usages\":[]},{\"type\":\"EVERGREEN\",\"prices\":[{\"currency\":\"IDR\",\"value\":250000}],\"fixedPrices\":[],\"duration\":{\"unit\":\"UNLIMITED\",\"number\":-1},\"usages\":[]}]},{\"name\":\"postpaid-monthly-trial7\",\"billingPeriod\":\"MONTHLY\",\"phases\":[{\"type\":\"TRIAL\",\"prices\":[],\"fixedPrices\":[{\"currency\":\"IDR\",\"value\":0}],\"duration\":{\"unit\":\"DAYS\",\"number\":7},\"usages\":[]},{\"type\":\"EVERGREEN\",\"prices\":[{\"currency\":\"IDR\",\"value\":350000}],\"fixedPrices\":[],\"duration\":{\"unit\":\"UNLIMITED\",\"number\":-1},\"usages\":[]}]}],\"included\":[],\"available\":[]},{\"type\":\"BASE\",\"name\":\"PrePaid\",\"plans\":[{\"name\":\"prepaid-signature-item\",\"billingPeriod\":\"NO_BILLING_PERIOD\",\"phases\":[{\"type\":\"EVERGREEN\",\"prices\":[],\"fixedPrices\":[],\"duration\":{\"unit\":\"UNLIMITED\",\"number\":-1},\"usages\":[{\"billingPeriod\":\"NO_BILLING_PERIOD\",\"tiers\":[{\"blocks\":[{\"unit\":\"item\",\"size\":\"1.0\",\"max\":\"5.0\",\"prices\":[{\"currency\":\"IDR\",\"value\":250000}]}],\"limits\":[],\"fixedPrice\":[],\"recurringPrice\":[]}]}]}]}],\"included\":[],\"available\":[]}],\"priceLists\":[{\"name\":\"DEFAULT\",\"plans\":[\"postpaid-monthly-fix\",\"postpaid-monthly-trial1\",\"postpaid-monthly-trial7\",\"prepaid-signature-item\"]}]},{\"name\":\"DEFAULT\",\"effectiveDate\":\"Apr 21, 2018 3:35:31 PM\",\"currencies\":[\"IDR\"],\"products\":[{\"type\":\"BASE\",\"name\":\"PostPaid\",\"plans\":[{\"name\":\"postpaid-monthly-fix\",\"billingPeriod\":\"MONTHLY\",\"phases\":[{\"type\":\"EVERGREEN\",\"prices\":[{\"currency\":\"IDR\",\"value\":300000}],\"fixedPrices\":[],\"duration\":{\"unit\":\"UNLIMITED\",\"number\":-1},\"usages\":[]}]},{\"name\":\"postpaid-monthly-trial1\",\"billingPeriod\":\"MONTHLY\",\"phases\":[{\"type\":\"TRIAL\",\"prices\":[],\"fixedPrices\":[{\"currency\":\"IDR\",\"value\":0}],\"duration\":{\"unit\":\"DAYS\",\"number\":1},\"usages\":[]},{\"type\":\"EVERGREEN\",\"prices\":[{\"currency\":\"IDR\",\"value\":250000}],\"fixedPrices\":[],\"duration\":{\"unit\":\"UNLIMITED\",\"number\":-1},\"usages\":[]}]},{\"name\":\"postpaid-monthly-trial7\",\"billingPeriod\":\"MONTHLY\",\"phases\":[{\"type\":\"TRIAL\",\"prices\":[],\"fixedPrices\":[{\"currency\":\"IDR\",\"value\":0}],\"duration\":{\"unit\":\"DAYS\",\"number\":7},\"usages\":[]},{\"type\":\"EVERGREEN\",\"prices\":[{\"currency\":\"IDR\",\"value\":350000}],\"fixedPrices\":[],\"duration\":{\"unit\":\"UNLIMITED\",\"number\":-1},\"usages\":[]}]}],\"included\":[],\"available\":[]},{\"type\":\"BASE\",\"name\":\"PrePaid\",\"plans\":[{\"name\":\"prepaid-signature-item\",\"billingPeriod\":\"NO_BILLING_PERIOD\",\"phases\":[{\"type\":\"EVERGREEN\",\"prices\":[],\"fixedPrices\":[],\"duration\":{\"unit\":\"UNLIMITED\",\"number\":-1},\"usages\":[{\"billingPeriod\":\"DAILY\",\"tiers\":[{\"blocks\":[{\"unit\":\"item\",\"size\":\"1.0\",\"max\":\"5.0\",\"prices\":[{\"currency\":\"IDR\",\"value\":250000}]}],\"limits\":[],\"fixedPrice\":[],\"recurringPrice\":[]}]}]}]}],\"included\":[],\"available\":[]}],\"priceLists\":[{\"name\":\"DEFAULT\",\"plans\":[\"postpaid-monthly-fix\",\"postpaid-monthly-trial1\",\"postpaid-monthly-trial7\",\"prepaid-signature-item\"]}]},{\"name\":\"DEFAULT\",\"effectiveDate\":\"Apr 21, 2018 3:38:31 PM\",\"currencies\":[\"IDR\"],\"products\":[{\"type\":\"BASE\",\"name\":\"PostPaid\",\"plans\":[{\"name\":\"postpaid-monthly-fix\",\"billingPeriod\":\"MONTHLY\",\"phases\":[{\"type\":\"EVERGREEN\",\"prices\":[{\"currency\":\"IDR\",\"value\":300000}],\"fixedPrices\":[],\"duration\":{\"unit\":\"UNLIMITED\",\"number\":-1},\"usages\":[]}]},{\"name\":\"postpaid-monthly-trial1\",\"billingPeriod\":\"MONTHLY\",\"phases\":[{\"type\":\"TRIAL\",\"prices\":[],\"fixedPrices\":[{\"currency\":\"IDR\",\"value\":0}],\"duration\":{\"unit\":\"DAYS\",\"number\":1},\"usages\":[]},{\"type\":\"EVERGREEN\",\"prices\":[{\"currency\":\"IDR\",\"value\":250000}],\"fixedPrices\":[],\"duration\":{\"unit\":\"UNLIMITED\",\"number\":-1},\"usages\":[]}]},{\"name\":\"postpaid-monthly-trial7\",\"billingPeriod\":\"MONTHLY\",\"phases\":[{\"type\":\"TRIAL\",\"prices\":[],\"fixedPrices\":[{\"currency\":\"IDR\",\"value\":0}],\"duration\":{\"unit\":\"DAYS\",\"number\":7},\"usages\":[]},{\"type\":\"EVERGREEN\",\"prices\":[{\"currency\":\"IDR\",\"value\":350000}],\"fixedPrices\":[],\"duration\":{\"unit\":\"UNLIMITED\",\"number\":-1},\"usages\":[]}]}],\"included\":[],\"available\":[]},{\"type\":\"BASE\",\"name\":\"PrePaid\",\"plans\":[{\"name\":\"prepaid-signature-item\",\"billingPeriod\":\"NO_BILLING_PERIOD\",\"phases\":[{\"type\":\"EVERGREEN\",\"prices\":[],\"fixedPrices\":[],\"duration\":{\"unit\":\"UNLIMITED\",\"number\":-1},\"usages\":[{\"billingPeriod\":\"DAILY\",\"tiers\":[{\"blocks\":[{\"unit\":\"item\",\"size\":\"1.0\",\"max\":\"5.0\",\"prices\":[{\"currency\":\"IDR\",\"value\":250000}]}],\"limits\":[],\"fixedPrice\":[],\"recurringPrice\":[]}]}]}]}],\"included\":[],\"available\":[]}],\"priceLists\":[{\"name\":\"DEFAULT\",\"plans\":[\"postpaid-monthly-fix\",\"postpaid-monthly-trial1\",\"postpaid-monthly-trial7\",\"prepaid-signature-item\"]}]}]\n";

JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) JSONValue.parseWithException(s);
List plans = (List)((Map)((List)((Map)jsonArray.get(0)).get("priceLists")).get(0)).get("plans");
System.out.println(plans);
System.out.println(plans.get(0));
System.out.println(plans.get(1));
System.out.println(plans.get(2));
System.out.println(plans.get(3));
```

Output:

```
["postpaid-monthly-fix","postpaid-monthly-trial1","postpaid-monthly-trial7","prepaid-signature-item"]
postpaid-monthly-fix
postpaid-monthly-trial1
postpaid-monthly-trial7
prepaid-signature-item
```